# Error loading mySQLdb module

Tags: python, django, centos, cpanel

I'm trying to run my app in my server with:

```
python2.7 manage.py runserver
```

And get the following:

```
 raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: /root/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
```

I'm search here by this error, but no success.

Running CentOS 5.8, Django, Python and cPanel.

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL-Python for 2.4 with Python 2.7? CentOS (which is what I think you meant to type) appears to have both 2.4 and 2.7 installed. As a starting point, you'll need to make sure Python 2.7 finds a more-appropriate installation of MySQL-Python.

Comment: Yes, i mean CentOS. So how can make python 2.7 find the MySQL-Python version?

Comment: I've installed the last version: 1.2.3 . Downloaded from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/?_test=b

Comment: Just install a fresh mysqldb module in your pytohn 2.7's site-packages

Comment: this sounds like your .python-eggs in noexec folder change your .python-eggs folder to something like /opt/.python-eggs/